# OpenSSL I need more information about PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY

Tags: c++, openssl

I don't have any problem, but I would like some explication about an openssl method:

```
RSA *PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(FILE *fp, RSA **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

The method is returning a RSA pointer, but we also have to give in entry an RSA double pointer. What is the point of doing both?

For example when I'm using the method the 3 following lines leads me to the same result:

```
key = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, &key, NULL, NULL);
key = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(file, &key, NULL, NULL);
```

In all the lines my object `key` is all good. So what solution should I use between the 3 above?

Comment: Are you sure its the same in memory allocation as well?

Comment: Not sure about anything, I can't find any documentation about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any solution that fits with your coding style (and with the coding style of the rest of your program).

Some programmers are more comfortable getting results from return values; others are more comfortable getting results by passing the result storage as input. Many OpenSSL methods (*but not all!*) are structured to provide this sort of flexibility.

Comment: Thank u, I was afraid to miss something, but if it's doing the same thing, it's cool!